# Adaptive Threshold CIKernel/CIFilter iOS

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, adaptive-threshold, cikernel

I have researched all over in order to find a kernel that performs adaptive thresholding on iOS. Unfortunately I do not understand the kernel language or the logic behind it. Below, I have found a routine that performs thresholding (https://gist.github.com/xhruso00/a3f8a9c8ae7e33b8b23d)

```
static NSString * const kKernelSource = @"kernel vec4 thresholdKernel(sampler image)\n"
"{\n"
"  float inputThreshold = 0.05;\n"
"  float pass = 1.0;\n"
"  float fail = 0.0;\n"
"  const vec4   vec_Y = vec4( 0.299, 0.587, 0.114, 0.0 );\n"
"  vec4  src = unpremultiply( sample(image, samplerCoord(image)) );\n"
"  float Y = dot( src, vec_Y );\n"
"  src.rgb = vec3( compare( Y - inputThreshold, fail, pass));\n"
"  return premultiply(src);\n"
"}";
```

Is it possible to rewrite this into an adaptive thresholding kernel? The image I am supplying to it has been turned into B&W and has already been blurred. Are there any resources you could point me to? I would like to stick with CoreImage as my whole stack is built around it.

Edit: The best example / reference from what I am trying to achieve has been implemented in GPUImage's GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter - https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/c5f0914152419437869c35e29858773b1a06083c/framework/Source/GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter.m

Comment: I updated my code with description, metal and modern approach https://gist.github.com/xhruso00/a3f8a9c8ae7e33b8b23d I inspired myself with below code but the code below doesn't respect alpha premultiplication (transparent areas will become black or white).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon's Filter is the right approach to achieve the desired effect, however, you have to modify a couple of things.

First of all, switch the order of `imageLuma` and `thresholdLuma`, since we want black letters to remain black and not the other way around. Also, you should add a constant (I chose `0.01`) to remove noise.

```
    var thresholdKernel =  CIColorKernel(string:
    "kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(__sample image, __sample threshold)" +
        "{" +
        "   float imageLuma = dot(image.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));" +
        "   float thresholdLuma = dot(threshold.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));" +
        "   return vec4(vec3(step(thresholdLuma, imageLuma+0.001)), 1);"     
    "}"

override var outputImage: CIImage! {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage,
        let thresholdKernel = thresholdKernel else {
        return nil
    }
    let blurred = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIBoxBlur", withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 5]) // block size
    let extent = inputImage.extent
    let arguments = [inputImage, blurred]
    return thresholdKernel.apply(withExtent: extent, arguments: arguments)
}
```

And this is, what you get Only using Apple's Core Image, without having to install any external libraries :)

[image]

Of course, you can play around a little with the values of constant and block size.

Comment: Pascal, thank you for your answer. Any idea on how to implement this in CoreImage too? https://github.com/ctodobom/OpenNoteScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/todobom/opennotescanner/ImageProcessor.java#L409

Comment: You mentioned a constant of 0.01 but you have 0.001, is this a mistake? Also, do you apply this constant to the imageLuma or the threshold luma (assuming i did want white letters with black background.

Comment: 0.01 and 0.001 doesn't seem to make too much of a difference. You may try different values to fit your need.

Answer (score 6):

How does this look: I've used the CoreImage `CIBoxBlur` (although the dedicated convolution filters *may* be faster) and passed the output of that into my [existing threshold filter](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/CustomFilters.swift).

```
class AdaptiveThresholdFilter: CIFilter
{
    var inputImage : CIImage?


    var thresholdKernel =  CIColorKernel(string:
    "kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(__sample image, __sample threshold)" +
    "{" +
    "   float imageLuma = dot(image.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));" +
    "   float thresholdLuma = dot(threshold.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));" +

    "   return vec4(vec3(step(imageLuma, thresholdLuma)), 1.0);" +
    "}"
    )


    override var outputImage: CIImage!
    {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage,
            thresholdKernel = thresholdKernel else
        {
            return nil
        }

        let blurred = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIBoxBlur",
               withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 9])

        let extent = inputImage.extent
        let arguments = [inputImage, blurred]

        return thresholdKernel.applyWithExtent(extent, arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

I found [this image](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/son1.gif) of a shaded page and with this code:

```
let page = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "son1.gif")!)

let filter = AdaptiveThresholdFilter()

filter.inputImage = page

let final = filter.outputImage
```

I got this result:

[image]

Cheers!

Simon

Comment: Thank you for getting me started. I was looking for something more along the lines of http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/son1adp2.gif however

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CIColorThresholdOtsu`  core image filter

Comment: This more recent answer is quite useful, too! If a developer writes a thresholding algorithm and just wants to apply the threshold, then CIColorThreshold is also worth a look: https://cifilter.io/CIColorThreshold/