# Convert colored NSImage into a pure black and white NSImage using CIFilters in swift

Tags: image-processing, swift4, grayscale, cifilter, ciimage

I am converting a colored NSImage into a black and white only (not grayscale) NSImage by applying CIFilters. However, the resulting image is distorted due to blurred edges in the original image.

I am new to swift and it would be great if someone could help me understand where am I going wrong or what is the best approach to get a clear black and white image from a colored image?

I tried to apply CICategorySharpen filter but the returned image is nil and Xcode aborts. When I exclude CICategorySharpen, the converted image is distorted. Apple documentation has not been very useful so far. I have seen some bitmap image approach online to handle the same which does not seem very efficient.

```
//url of NSImage
let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url)!

// Sharpen the image - currently returns nil and Xcode aborts
let sharpImage = CIFilter(name: "CICategorySharpen", parameters:    [kCIInputImageKey: ciImage] )?.outputImage

// Convert image into grayscale
let grayImage = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sharpImage])?.outputImage

// Convert into black and white
let bAndWParams: [String: Any] = [kCIInputImageKey: grayImage,
                                  kCIInputContrastKey: 50.0,
                                  kCIInputBrightnessKey: 10.0]

let blackAndWhiteImage = (CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls", parameters: bAndWParams)?.outputImage)!

//Convert back into NSImage
let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: blackAndWhiteImage)
let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)
```

Expected: Clear, sharp black and white image after applying CIfilters irrespective of the quality of the original image.

Actual:
1. Without CICategorySharpen, the black and white images are distorted after conversion.
2. When I add CICategorySharpen, Xcode aborts.

Comment: Can you please show what you mean by "distorted"?

Comment: `CICategorySharpen` is just the name of the _category_. You need to pick a sharpen filter from that category, like `CISharpenLuminance`. I doubt that a sharpened image would yield better results in this case, though.

Comment: My original rectangle is - https://ibb.co/tB5m8HV and converted rectangle is - https://ibb.co/TMvvP3H. After conversion, the rectangle has rough edges. I need a rectangle with smooth edges. This is causing distortion in other images. Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty good solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184255/adaptive-threshold-cikernel-cifilter-ios